# the difference between bundle and resource in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I am doing an reading about the [bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html) and [resource](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i.)

Somehow these terms are very blur to me now. What I am imagining right now  is that *resource* is one of the sub-folders of *bundle*. 
My question is: is that the right thought and if not, please correct me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resource can be any file (or folder of files) that your application needs but which isn't part of the compiled binary.  They can be things like mp3 or wav files, or png graphics, or translation strings...and many other possibilities.  A bundle is a folder with some special properties that contains resources and, for the default app bundle, also the compiled/linked part of the application itself.

Comment: should bundle has an extension .app at the end such as MyApp.app ?

Comment: Some do and some don't.  It depends on their purpose.

Answer (score 1):

No its not, the resource is your project (yellow map), is a group. And almost all the files in that group group gat copied in to the bundle (which is in iOS is the .app folder). You can look at it this way: The executable, nibs, images and so on are copied in to the main bundle aka the .app folder.

Thus when we speak about nibs, image, translation files we call them resources.

The resource folder (group) is just there for convenience.

You can create folders with in you bundle by dragging them in to you project and select `Create folders references for any added folders`

Comment: @borrrden+rckoenes : thanks for your all comments. There is still sth in my head now. I can see folder named **Resources** +  **Supporting Files** (yellow folders)+ect... on the left hand side of xcode. So, are they one of the **resource** which are we talking about.

Comment: The resources Apple talks about in the developer documentation are just files you may want in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Bundles have much less relevance on ios than they do on os x.  Each bundle is its own executable file, and you can call them like a command line tool.  iOS apps usually (always?) have just one bundle.  A resource is something used by the bundle.  You must include some information about a bundle's content and main execution method to be able to actually load them into memory.  If you dont actually load them then they can be quick tools to make files out of folders.